# Compare blob files with bytes in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Earlier logic is comparing the files which is stored in windows folder location. Please see the below code for comparing 2 files based on bytes

```
const int BYTES_TO_READ = 1024;

public static bool filesAreDifferent(string file1, string file2) {
    FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(file1);
    FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(file2);

    if (!fi1.Exists || !fi2.Exists) return true;
    if (fi1.Length != fi2.Length) return true;

    int iterations = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fi1.Length / BYTES_TO_READ);

    using (FileStream fs1 = fi1.OpenRead())
    using (FileStream fs2 = fi2.OpenRead()) {
        byte[] one = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];
        byte[] two = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            fs1.Read(one, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
            fs2.Read(two, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
           if (!one.SequenceEqual(two)) return true;            
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now I want to comapre 2 files which is stored in blob container.
Below is what i tried so far (tweaking the old logic),

```
public static CloudBlobContainer GetStorageAccount(bool IsCreateIfNotExists)
{
    var ff = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
    string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
    string configvalue2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"];

    CloudBlobContainer blob = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"])
                       .CreateCloudBlobClient()
                       .GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobCotainer"]);

    if(IsCreateIfNotExists)
       blob.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    return blob;

}

public static bool filesAreDifferentBlob(string file1, string file2)
{
    CloudBlockBlob fil1 = GetStorageAccount(true).GetBlockBlobReference(file1);
    CloudBlockBlob fil2 = GetStorageAccount(true).GetBlockBlobReference(file2);
    fil1.FetchAttributes();
    fil2.FetchAttributes();

    if (!fil1.Exists() || !fil2.Exists()) return true;
    if (fil1.Properties.Length != fil1.Properties.Length) return true;

    int iterations = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fil1.Properties.Length / BYTES_TO_READ);
    using (StreamReader fsf1 = new StreamReader(fil1.OpenRead()))
    using (StreamReader fsf2 = new StreamReader(fil2.OpenRead()))
    {
       byte[] one = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];
       byte[] two = new byte[BYTES_TO_READ];

       for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
       {
         fsf1.Read(one, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
         fsf2.Read(two, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
         if (!one.SequenceEqual(two)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But i am getting the error "Cannot convert from byte[] to char[]".
Is there any way to compare to 2 files from blob?

Comment: fsf1.Read(one, 0, BYTES_TO_READ); This is the line where exception is thrown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why StreamReader returns string instead of byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083926/why-streamreader-returns-string-instead-of-byte-array)

Comment: have you considered comparing the ContentMD5 hash of your blobs instead of comparing all bytes yourself?

Comment: No I didn't consider ContentMD5.
For time being, i have updated the code like below, 
using (StreamReader fsf1 = new StreamReader(fil1.OpenRead()))
using (StreamReader fsf2 = new StreamReader(fil2.OpenRead()))
{
   byte[] one = fsf1.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(fsf1.ReadToEnd());
   byte[] two = fsf2.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(fsf2.ReadToEnd());
   if (!one.SequenceEqual(two)) return true;         
}

I am not sure this will this is good approach to compare files from blob

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, Now i have changed my code to compare the file with ContentMD5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to compare to 2 files from blob?

As Thomas mentioned that we could compare the [ContentMD5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contentmd5?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobProperties_ContentMD5) hash of your blobs instead of comparing all bytes. We could easily get [ContentMD5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contentmd5?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobProperties_ContentMD5) hash of you blobs.

```
fil1.FetchAttributes();
fil2.FetchAttributes();
if (!fil1.Exists() || !fil2.Exists()) return true;
if (fil1.Properties.ContentMD5!= fil2.Properties.ContentMD5) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
I will compare with ContentMD5 instead of converting to bytes, since it is time consuming for bigger files.